# Index few attributes of document in hybris Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, sap-commerce-cloud

We have around 100k products in our website and each product have around 30 attributes which are indexed. Most of the time we only update price of products but we still have to index the whole product. Is it possible in hybris to index only the price attribute(or description attribute) of all 100k products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible since Solr 4.0. This feature is called partial update, where you can update only the fields changed, in your case, price and description.
The official documentation is [here](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/updating-parts-of-documents.html).

Answer (score 1):

Marco is right. You can do a Partial Update.

For Hybris, there is some documentation is in [Creating and Configuring Indexed Types](https://help.hybris.com/1808/hcd/bc912462e6974ac596b252cd18680e4e.html#loiobc912462e6974ac596b252cd18680e4e). SolrIndexerQuery.type attribute lets you choose `partial_update`.

```
You have the following values to choose from:
FULL: recreates the index
UPDATE: updates some documents in the index
PARTIAL_UPDATE: allows you to select the fields for the update
DELETE: deletes documents from the index
```

[image]